# How to read file to import matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to use some matrices in Python programs, like

```
Q = np.matrix([[1,0,1,1,0],
               [0,2,0,1,1],
               [1,0,2,0,1],
               [1,1,0,1,0],
               [0,1,1,0,1]])
```

and I want to import the matrix (use numpy) from a file, so what should I do to realize it? what code should I write and what file should I use (.txt?). I am quite new to python, anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends. Can you decide the format of the file, or is it pre-existing data that you have to deal with? If you can decide the format, is having it be human-readable/editable more important than having it be small and fast?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are pre-existing data, just some matrices. For example, store one matrix in a file, and then in the programs let Q be the matrix. If it can be human-readable, it is better. I am considering to use a .txt format. Is it very difficult to realize?

Comment: By "pre-existing data", I meant "do you have to read files someone else gave you"? If not, then it's very easy to realize. If so… it depends on the file format you were given, but it's usually not hard.

Comment: Nope, I don't have to, but I will tell others who will test my code to use the similar file just by changing the data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're not only importing the matrices, but also exporting them to files in the first place.

If that's true, there are multiple easy options, with different tradeoffs.

---

[`np.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) saves the array in a binary format that's only usable by NumPy. But it's very fast, and generates reasonably small files.

```
np.save('matrix.npy', Q)
Q = np.load('matrix.npy')
```

---

[`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) saves the array in a text file, using a dialect of CSV (with whitespace separators, by default). It's slower, and generates bigger files, but if you want to be able to read or edit the files (or send them through an ASCII-only channel, like email without attachments), it's the best option.

```
np.savetxt('matrix.txt', Q)
Q = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt')
```

---

[`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) can *also* save the array in a compressed text file. This gives you small files, but they're slower to save and load. They're not directly human-readable, but it's very easy to un-gzip a file, and then you've got a text file you *can* read and edit. So, sometimes this is worth doing.

```
np.savetxt('matrix.txt.gz', Q)
Q = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt.gz')
```

---

Finally, you can just use standard Python saving and loading mechanisms, like [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
with open('matrix.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(Q, f)
with open('matrix.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    Q = pickle.load(f)
```

This is really only useful if you need to store NumPy arrays together with non-NumPy objects.

---

If you have to save *multiple* matrices, instead of saving one per file, you might want to look at [`savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) and [`savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed). Or, if you need multiple objects, only some of which are NumPy, `pickle` may be the best option.